# How to search tuple with three elements inside list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list as below

```
tlist=[(‘abc’,HYD,’user1’), (‘xyz’,’SNG’,’user2’), (‘pppp’,’US’,’user3’), (‘qq’,’HK’,’user4’)]
```

I want to display the second field tuple of provided first field of tuple.

```
Ex:
tlist(‘xyz’) 
SNG
```

Is there way to get it?

Comment: Essentially what you are doing is a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there would be multiple tuples with `xyz` as a first item, use the following simple approach(with modified example):

```
tlist = [('abc','HYD','user1'), ('xyz','SNG','user2'), ('pppp','US','user3'), ('xyz','HK','user4')]
second_fields = [f[1] for f in tlist if f[0] == 'xyz']

print(second_fields)  # ['SNG', 'HK']
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply,
you made it simple and good, it worked

Comment: @SrinivasGadi, glad to help

Answer (score 4):

A tuple doesn't have a hash table lookup like a dictionary, so you will need to loop through it in sequence until you find it:

```
def find_in_tuple(tlist, search_term):
    for x, y, z in tlist:
        if x == search_term:
            return y

print(find_in_tuple(tlist, 'xyz')) # prints 'SNG'
```

If you plan to do this multiple times, you definitely want to convert to a dictionary. I would recommend making the first element of the tuple the key and then the other two the values for that key. You can do this very easily using a dictionary comprehension.

```
>>> tlist_dict = { k: (x, y) for k, x, y in tlist } # Python 3: { k: v for k, *v in tlist }
>>> tlist_dict
{'qq': ['HK', 'user4'], 'xyz': ['SNG', 'user2'], 'abc': ['HYD', 'user1'], 'pppp': ['US', 'user3']}
```

You can then select the second element as follows:

```
>>> tlist_dict['xyz'][0]
'SNG'
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay ,I am getting the syntax error
>>> tlist_dict = { k: (x, y) for k, x, y in tlist }
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    tlist_dict = { k: (x, y) for k, x, y in tlist }
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
not sure when i was wrong

Comment: @SrinivasGadi I just tried it in Python 2.7.10 and 3.5.1 and it worked: are you sure you're using Python 2.7? Earlier versions don't have dict comprehension